# 11x11 box filter kernel

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to blur an image using an 11x11 box filter kernel. But I keep getting the following error:

```
    add = image.item(i+k, j+l)
    IndexError: index 600 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 600
```

My code for this part:

```
for i in np.arange(3, height-3):
for j in np.arange(3, width-3):
    sum = 0
    for k in np.arange(-5,6):
        for l in np.arange(-5,6):
            add = image.item(i+k, j+l)
            sum = sum+add
    avg = int(sum/121.0)  #for 11x11, average is sum/121
    image_output3.itemset((i,j), avg)
```

Comment: Do you understand that indices are zero based? So that for a container of length 600 the last index is 599?  Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: An 11x11 box around a pixel results in indices +6 and -5 relative to the pixel's index. Two options: pad the array on all the edges so that you won't get IndexErrors or start/stop iterating at indices that have sufficient space around them.  or iterate over slices with starting points that range from (0,0) to `(image.shape[0]-11, image.shape[1]-11)`

Answer (score 0):

`for i in np.arange(3, height-3)` indicates you’re looping over the image and leaving a 3-pixel boundary.

`for k in np.arange(-5,6)` indicates you’re looping over a kernel that needs a 5-pixel boundary.

`image.item(i+k, j+l)` shows what `i+k` must be between 0 (included) and `height` (excluded). Given the limits above, it’s actually between `3-5=-2` (included) and `height-3+6=height+3` (excluded). Obviously you’ll be indexing out of bounds.

The solution then is to adjust the boundary in the outer loops, so they are `np.arange(5, height-5)`.